# Android Spinner not reacting to any click event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I built a custom `Spinner` and it has a method to load some data and once these data are loaded (in the `ArrayList` events), they're displayed.

Everything is working except some annoying stuff: I detect any click event on this spinner (to change the selected item), my `OnItemSelectedListener` is only triggered once at the beginning...

But better than blabla, here is the code:

```
public class ActionChooser extends Spinner {
    private Context c;
    ArrayList<Event> events;
    OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public ActionChooser(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.c = context;
        init();
    }

    public ActionChooser(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.c = context;
        init();
    }


    private void init() {
        // events arrayList is filled by a XML parser there, too long and uninteresting for SO
        setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
        OnItemSelectedListener l = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.d("ActionChooser", "i:" + i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                Log.d("ActionChooser", "nothing");
            }
        };
        setOnItemSelectedListener(l);
    }


    private class Event {

        String methodSignature;
        String name;
        boolean isBefore;
        ArrayList<Param> data;
    }

    private class Param {
        int pos;
        String name;
    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return events.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return events.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View row = inflate(c, R.layout.row_action_chooser, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView methodName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.javaM);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.dataContainer);
            tv.setText(WordUtils.capitalize(events.get(i).name));
            methodName.setText(events.get(i).methodSignature);
            cb.setChecked(events.get(i).isBefore);
            for (Param p : events.get(i).data) {
                TextView pt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.parameterTitle);
                pt.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                TextView ptv = new TextView(c);
                ptv.setText(p.name + " (pos: " + p.pos + ")");
                ptv.setTextSize(10);
                ll.addView(ptv);
            }
            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

The spinner looks more or less fine:

[image]

But I cannot click on it (actually I can but it does nothing, it doesn't even make the popup disappear...).

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

Guys, never put ANY `Checkbox` in subview of `Spinner`. That's the problem and if you remove the `Checkbox` it works just fine!

Comment: Hum, why not yes, but actually I will just delete the Android Question and report it ;)